# Android Studio New Setup. Version 1.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio

When I first downloaded Android Studio, the layout for everything was fine. But now it has changed. Also I find it confusing for trying to open an existing project. Unfortunately I can't upload photos because of my reputation lack, so if anyone knows how I can give 'evidence', then please tell me.

The New Project tab is different, asking me for java or griffin or gradle etc. The file explorer in the actual project doesn't have the app folder, only the .ideas folder. I don't know how to edit my project!

If anyone can hep me out with this, then please let me know!

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you check out their documentation first: https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

Comment: The documentation shows the directory with an app file. All I have is a .idea file.

Comment: Did you try click on the drop down and changing it to the Project view

Comment: Looks like you're now running IntelliJ IDEA instead of Android Studio. Android Studio has no support for Griffon projects.

Comment: @MrEngineer13 I always use the project view. And yole. How do I run Android Studio instead then? I click on the Android Studio dhortcut. Also as I said in my question, when I make a new project it asks me if I want Java or Griffon and more. I always choose Java.

Comment: @yole - is that really true? I had the understanding that AS was built on top of the community version. The community version supports Griffon projects, so couldn't/shouldn't it be possible with a download?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Android Studio removes a number of plugins from the Community Edition distribution which are not relevant for Android development. Those plugins are not published separately to the plugin repository. You could in principle copy them over from a matching installation of Community Edition, but I don't see why anyone would want to do that.

Comment: @TechnoSwag Have you tried reinstalling Android Studio?

Comment: @yole Yes I have. It still does the same thing.

Comment: So... Does anyone really know how I can fix this? I've tries reinstalling it and nothing happened, and there was nothinng in the documentation.

Comment: I still need an answer. My future in android development depends on getting this fixed.